# Share component on multiple pages NextJS and avoid re render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

As mentioned in the title I have tabs component with few links.

**tabs**:

```
<AppBar color="default" position="relative">
  <Tabs indicatorColor="primary" textColor="primary" value={activeTab} onChange={handleTabChange}>
          {tabs.map((tab, i) => ( <Tab label={tab.label} id={`tab-${i}`} key={i} />))}
   </Tabs>
</AppBar>
```

I have this tabs component placed in layout like this

```
<Container>
   <TabsComponent />
   {children}
</Container>
```

Now on each page I wrap my page content with this layout. Forgot to mention that these are nested routes.

Folder structure looks like this:

settings

- application.tsx -> contains layout component
- profile.tsx -> contains layout component

  ...

However this solution re-renders my tab component whenever I switch the page. Is there any way I can prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [custom App file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) to add your TabsComponent to the whole app, like the following:

```
// _app.js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return(
        <>
          **<TabsComponent />**
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp
```